# Slow internet upload speed when wired to ethernet adapter Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I have Asus ZenBook 14 with dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 18.04. I connected to internet with Unitek adapter USB3.0 Gigabit. Download speed is as expected but with upload I get only 0.42 Mbit/s. When connected to wifi speed is ok. Also checked how adapter works on Windows on my machine and upload speed also is fine.

Any ideas on how to investigate what is causing a problem? Thanks!

Edited:

Output of `lshw -C network`

```
  *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 30
   serial: a0:a4:c5:b5:68:69
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet 
   physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-51- 
   generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 
   wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
  *-network:0
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: docker0
   serial: 02:42:cc:e6:08:af
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 
   firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: br-51c144832e4c
   serial: 02:42:5d:89:cc:d4
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 
   firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:2
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@1:1.1
   logical name: enx000ec6cd87f1
   serial: 00:0e:c6:cd:87:f1
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a duplex=full ip=192.168.0.194 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. What is "Unitek adapter USB3.0 Gigabit"? Is it plugged into a USB3 port? Do you have a model # for this adapter so I can look it up? What ISP speed for cable/DSL?

Comment: You can find my adapter via `ua0174a`. Yes, it is plugged into my USB port. Upload ISP speed is ~ 50 Mbit/s

Comment: A few things wrong with this adapter from 2013. It's only USB 2.0. It's only rated for 100Mbs (even though lshw shows 1G) and you're only getting a 100Mbs connection. It's got a non-powered USB hub. First, try unplugging any USB devices plugged in and see if any improvement. Second, use cat 5e or cat 6 ethernet cables and see if any improvement. If you have USB3 ports, a better adapter is https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00YUU3KC6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: I've also tried with adapter Y-3046A, upload speed didn't change

Comment: What are the USB ports set to in the BIOS... legacy or something else? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and is "Asus ZenBook 14" the complete model #?